# Python3.4 A quest about create mul-threads

Tags: multithreading, python-3.4

look at this code:

```
def w(i):
    print("%s start" % i)
    time.sleep(10)
    print("end %s waiting" % i)


class ss(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, i):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.i = i

    def run(self):
        print("%s start" % self.i)
        time.sleep(10)
        print("end %s waiting" % self.i)

c=ss("c")
c.start()
d=ss("d")
d.start()

threading.Thread(w("a")).start()
threading.Thread(w("b")).start()
```

the result is this:

```
c start
a start
d start
end c waiting
end a waiting
end d waiting
b start
end b waiting
```

Maybe you have been know my puzzle.I create thread via "threading.Thread" function,it not run synchronously.Is it global function just only one thread run one time?I use python3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
threading.Thread(w("a")).start()
```

means execute `w("a")` and pass result to a `threading.Thread()` constructor. Instead of passing a callable object you are calling it. You need to separate function and it's arguments:

```
threading.Thread(target = w, args = ["a"]).start()
```

Comment: Thank you.This is the reason.